# String validation in basic chess model

Tags: java, regex, string

I get a string which size is 16 (location of chess pieces on the mini-chess-board). This string may contain only symbols:

1. K (king)
2. P (pawn)
3. N(knight)
4. R(rook)
5. B(bishop)
6. Q (queen)
7. and whitespaces (free field).

How can i validate this string with regex to check if string size is really 16, symbols are only of these and also it should necessarily contain one K symbol (because one King should be)

I tried [KQBNRP ]{16} but now cant check for a K symbol

Thank you

Comment: `Q` does not appear in your list of symbols. I guess it means **Queen**. `Q` should also appear only once in the string, no?

Comment: @Abra yeah, you're right, but different is King must be, Queen may be or may not

Comment: it even doesn't matter because i just want to know how to work with regex in this case, when string should be one size and keep a certain symbol for a once.

Comment: Use negative lookahead  to rule out 2 K's: `(?!.*K.*K)[KQBNRP ]{16}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know exactly which chars are allowed, you could use a single positive lookahead assertion for a single occurrence of `K`

Then match any of the listed 16 times using your pattern `[KQBNRP ]{16}`

```
^(?=[QBNRP ]*K[QBNRP ]*$)[KQBNRP ]{16}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W7AUVm/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that form the current position what is on the right is

  - `[QBNRP ]*K[QBNRP ]*$` Match a K between what is in the character class except for the K
- `)` Close the group
- `[KQBNRP ]{16}` Match 16 times any of the listed
- `$` End of string